# iframe contentDocument coming null while applying CSS override

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am facing an issue while applying CSS on content loaded into an iframe. After rendering iframe, in componentdidmount, i am calling a method to update content document to apply CSS overrides. But, contentdocument is coming null. Tried to use an intermediate method to check if document state is ready, then call override method otherwise, call same intermediate method to check again. But always, contentDocument is coming null.

Is there a way to apply CSS on content loaded into iframe, or to get value in contentDocument

Code snippet here -

```
private iframeRef: React.RefObject<HTMLIFrameElement>;

constructor(props: IIframeViewProps) {
    super(props);
    this.iframeRef = React.createRef();
}

public async componentDidMount(): Promise < void> {
    this.updateContentDocument();
}


public render(): JSX.Element | null {
    return (
        <iframe
            aria-label='iframe content'
            src='any external URL'
            ref={this.iframeRef}
            width='100%'
            height='700px'
            // tslint:disable-next-line:react-iframe-missing-sandbox
            sandbox='allow-scripts allow-forms allow-same-origin'
        />
    );
}

private updateContentDocument = (): void => {

    if (this.iframeRef && this.iframeRef.current) {
        const innerDocument = this.iframeRef.current.contentDocument;
        const css = 'body h1{font-size:50px;color:red}';

        if (innerDocument) {
            innerDocument.open();

            if (css) {
                // Append custom style
                const style = document.createElement('style');
                const cssNote = document.createTextNode(css);
                style.type = 'text/css';
                style.appendChild(cssNote);
                innerDocument.head.appendChild(style);
            }

            innerDocument.close();
        }
    }
}
```